# Removing one item from map removes all items

Tags: swift, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Map in my Firestore Database, looks like that:
[image]

I'm trying to remove just one item from the `following` map, like that:

```
func removeUserFromFriendsList(friendToRemove id: String, _ currentUserId: String, completion: @escaping(Bool)->()) {
    let friendsRef = db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).document(currentUserId)
    friendsRef.updateData([
        USER_FOLLOWING: FieldValue.arrayRemove([id])
    ]) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            completion(false)
        }
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

but instead of removing the item with the `ID` I got, it removes the whole list inside `following`

Comment: I think you're updating the whole collection instead of removing the item. Try to get the reference of the friend that you want to remove then use friendsRef.delete()

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem was that I was in the `following` level, and didn't specify the id to delete correctly. so It just deleted everything inside `following`.
Specifying the id and deleting it like that did the trick:

```
func removeUserFromFriendsList(friendToRemove id: String, _ currentUserId: String, completion: @escaping(Bool)->()) {
        let friendsRef = db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).document(currentUserId)
        friendsRef.updateData([
            USER_FOLLOWING + "." + id : FieldValue.delete()
        ]) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                completion(false)
            }
            completion(true)
        }
    }
```

`USER_FOLLOWING` is the name of the field in the database (aka, 'following').

Adding the + "."+ and the id just specify which id we want to delete, so it looks likes that:

```
following.AP3ENXgW2mhvaWsUeDOxchYaAGm1 <--- the field and id to delete
```

and then using `FieldValue.delete` to delete it entirely.

EDIT: 
Answer found here:

[How to remove an array item from a nested document in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875241/how-to-remove-an-array-item-from-a-nested-document-in-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

> Following the **example** from the  **[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):**

```
let friendsRef = db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).document(currentUserId)

// Atomically removes an ID from the "USER_FOLLOWING" array field.
friendsRef.updateData([
    "USER_FOLLOWING": FieldValue.arrayRemove([id])
])
```

If this is not an option for you, a **workaround** for this would be to read the entire array out of the document, make modifications to it in memory, then update the modified array field entirely.

Comment: I am not sure what `USER_FOLLOWING` stands for, but I think you need to give it right path to the field you are trying to update as @JohnDoah mentioned.