# Firebase Remove An Array Item

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to remove one value from an array in Firestore. I am using firebase functions and am updating this field after the deletion of a User. I have tried updating the array, I have tried arrayRemove, and a variety of other lines. Because I have to deploy every time I want to run a test it is getting time consuming and data is difficult to build and delete every time.

So I was hoping someone could help with this solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875241/how-to-remove-an-array-item-from-a-nested-document-in-firebase):

I want to loop through a list of IDs (Users in the DB) and pull out their matches, and remove a specific ID from their list of matches.

When I run this, it doesn't know what `firebase.firestore` is. So I am not sure how to register firestore with this type of `FieldValue.delete()`. What is this section looking to target? "admin.FieldValue.delete()"?

```
admin.firestore()
.collection("Users")
.doc(matches[i])
.update({
  [userId]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
});
```

I have also tried this:

```
admin
.firestore()
.collection("Users")
.doc(matches[i])
.update({
  matches: admin.firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId),
});
```

but again it doesn't know what `firebase.firestore` is. What is the correct method to removing one value from an array?

Also, I am concerned about making a callout in a for loop but I am not seeing a way around it. Does anyone have any suggestions? These don't need to be async as all of the transactions are not reliant on one another.

error message i get in firebase functions:

> ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you imported the Admin SDK like this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

You will want to use `admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()`.  Same pattern for `arrayRemove()`.